# JWT cookie security

Tags: javascript, next.js, cookies, jwt

I have a JWT stored as follows, and am wondering - is it safe to have an expiry date 30 days into the future and have the JWT stored in a cookie?

I want it to persist longer than a session, similar to the "Keep me logged in" functionality some websites have.

I have samesite:strict and httpOnly set to mitigate XSS and CSRF.

I am using NextJS

```
let resp = NextResponse.json({v:"returnedJSON"})

var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));             // in milliseconds ==30d

resp.cookies.set('token', jwtTokenString, {
    httpOnly: true,
    path: '/',
    secure: true,
    expires: date,
    sameSite: 'strict'           
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: Open to security risks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good solution, but it really depends on your application and risk appetite. I usually recommend the [OWASP CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html), which has the following basic principles:

> - First, check if your framework has built-in CSRF protection and use it
> - If the framework does not have built-in CSRF protection, add CSRF tokens to all state changing requests (requests that cause actions on
>   the site) and validate them on the backend
> - Stateful software should use the synchronizer token pattern
> - Stateless software should use double submit cookies
> - If an API-driven site can't use  tags, consider using custom request headers
> - Implement at least one mitigation from Defense in Depth Mitigations section
> - SameSite Cookie Attribute can be used for session cookies but be careful to NOT set a cookie specifically for a domain. This action
>   introduces a security vulnerability because all subdomains of that
>   domain will share the cookie, and this is particularly an issue if a
>   subdomain has a CNAME to domains not in your control.
> - Consider implementing user interaction based protection for highly sensitive operations
> - Consider verifying the origin with standard headers
> - Do not use GET requests for state changing operations.
> - If for any reason you do it, protect those resources against CSRF